# Move dynamically created image to a new page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I can dynamically create a barcode using sample tutorials.
This block of code is in a loop and generates a number of images determined by user input. The image is in a place holder and is displayed on the same webpage. 
I want the user to be able to have all the images on a separate page or file for them to print, but I'm not quite sure the best approach to do that. I tried placing it in a session, but I only get 1 image as opposed to the amount the user entered.

```
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image imgBarCode = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
using (Bitmap bitMap = new Bitmap(barCode.Length * 27, 100))
{
   using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitMap))
   {
       Font oFont = new Font("IDAutomationHC39M", 16);
       PointF point = new PointF(2f, .2f);
       SolidBrush blackBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
       SolidBrush whiteBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
       graphics.FillRectangle(whiteBrush, 0, 0, bitMap.Width, bitMap.Height);
       graphics.DrawString("*" + barCode + "*", oFont, blackBrush, point);
   }
    using (System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
    {
         bitMap.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
         byte[] byteImage = ms.ToArray();
         Convert.ToBase64String(byteImage);
         imgBarCode.ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(byteImage);

     }

        plBarCode.Controls.Add(imgBarCode);
}
```

Comment: What does the HTML output look like? Perhaps specifying the `imgBarCode` Name property would help, otherwise how are the `<IMG` tags named and spaced in the panel?

Comment: With this event, the html shows it as being displayed as a placeholder. What I'm trying to figure out is how do I get it from being drawn to having an img source. Because it will show with user input the amount of images generated with the place holder, but if I save the file or store it in a session to another page, it will only show one of the images. I've tried writing a method to generate the barcode and then call it in an event, but still only getting 1 image as a result.